# How to use django AppConfig.ready()

Tags: python, django, django-models

I can't seem to get my ready function under my AppConfig to work.

Here is my code from apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save, post_delete
from django.db.models import Max, Count
from .models import Player, PlayerStats, TotalLevels

class BloxorsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'bloxors'

    def ready(self):
        MaxCurrentLevel = PlayerStats.objects.aggregate(max_levels=Max('level_no'))['max_levels']
        PlayerCount = Player.objects.aggregate(count_players=Count('player_name', distinct=True))['count_players']
        print(MaxCurrentLevel, PlayerCount)
```

I read in the documentation that ready() gets called each time at the beginning of `manage.py runserver` but then why does nothing happen. Ideally I was expecting it to print the two values `MaxCurrentLevel, PlayerCount`.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong and help solve this?

As always, I greatly appreciate your answers!

Comment: Did you add your app in the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @PedramParsian Yes, I have!

Comment: Try print("Test") within `ready` for debugging purposes please to see if it calls the function at all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok this was a bit stupid of me in the first place, but I found the answer and to anyone else that would like it, here it is!

Under INSTALLED_APPS:
I had installed my app as:
`'bloxors'`

but apparently in the documentation (after a decent amount of digging), You need to actually specify it as:

`'bloxors.apps.BloxorsConfig'`

The reason given was because, there is no default AppConfig set by django and it is upto the user to do so, which I wasn't aware of, so here you go!