# Django AppConfig ready()

Tags: django, django-apps

I have Django 2.1.7

I read Django documentation as well as, this [How to use django AppConfig.ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59225246/how-to-use-django-appconfig-ready?noredirect=1&lq=1) and this [Overriding AppConfig.ready()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37429726/overriding-appconfig-ready).

Now, the folder/file structure is like this,

```
my_app
 __init__.py
 urls.py
 sub_app1
  migrations
  __init__.py
  admin.py
  apps.py
  models.py
  ...
 sub_app2
  ...
 sub_app3
  ...
```

and all `sub_app`s are registered into `INSTALLED_APPS` of Django `settings.py` file as `my_app.sub_app1` for example. I noticed that when I try to override `ready()`for `sub_app1` w/in `sub_app1.apps.py`, overriding has no effect.

When I flatten my structure above as

```
my_app
 __init__.py
 urls.py
 apps.py
```

overriding of `ready` works fine.

In other words, it seems that overriding of `ready`of a sub app w/in sub app's `apps.py` doesn't work.

Also, whether using `default_app_config` w/in sub app's `__init__.py` or `my_app.sub_app1.apps.SubApp1Config` w/in `settings.py INSTALLED_APPS` it gives error `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot import 'sub_app1'. Check that 'my_app.sub_app1.apps.SubApp1Config.name' is correct.`

Why is this happening?